# Changing Gridview row color based on some condition without using rowdatabound event

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I am displaying employee details like name, email, contact and bday in gridview I want to change color of row based on some condition(If isActive is 0, then display in red color, Isactive is not part of gridview column), Most important thing I dont want to use RowDataBound event(I want to do this in .aspx page). I am using Linq to EF.

Comment: Any specific reason why you don't want to do it in `RowDataBound` event? Also post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery for this

```
$("#GridViewId tr").each(function()
{ 
if($(this).find("td:eq(3)").text()=="0") 
 $(this).css('color','red'); 
});
```

Here it will look for value `0` in 4th column of `gridview`. You can change it to where this column lies.`Index` starts from 0.

Comment: What if IsActive is not column in gridview?

Comment: So you will need some column on basis of which you can do this.

Comment: You can add a data-active attribute to filter with JQuery as mentioned @Mairaj Ahmad. Could you please put the HTML code you have done ?

Answer (score -1):

try this code in `RowDataBound`

```
protected void Grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            string isActive = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "isActive"));

            if (isActive == "0")
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#28b779");//81F79F
                e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
            }
            else
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#da5554");//F78181
                e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the question I have clearly mention that I dont want to use RowDatabound event.

Comment: why dont use RowDatabound event?

Comment: That doesn't answer to the subject. It is a good solution but not for this topic.